# Error in loading HomeComponent, Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-httpclient

I am trying to build an app using "An API of Ice and Fire". I am getting this error 
`ERROR Error: "[object Object]"` when I try to redirect to homeComponent. 
Here is the screenshot of the error:

[Before redirecting to home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xgtA.png)

[on home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMRra.png)

Ah, one more thing, I think the shell page is not getting redirected to the homepage, because the URL doesn't change to `http://localhost:4200/home`.

I am attaching the [plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/tT9052BMEIZ1PkmqUtgi/) of my code. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: How can the error be reproduced in plunker ?

Comment: It shows a { error in scripts.js. Where is that file?

Comment: I can see the error in console. Please share me your code.

Comment: @AdrianFâciu The plunk was just to have a look at my code. I am not sure how else to show it.

Comment: @Code_maniac: I am not sure about the file because when I click on it, it redirects me to "*//*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css " with some CSS code.

Comment: @kyl Can you please tell me how? There are lot of files and codes?

Comment: @Code_maniac I found the file. it's the boostrap.css.min file which I have installed and saved in my node_modules and included in my angular.json scripts[ ]. But the error is strange as it's showing that there is an unexpected " { " in line number 5 after the selector html,  but line number 5 is : `html { /**css code**/ }`. How can this be a syntax error?

Comment: Please add all css in styles[] array and not scripts array inside angular.json

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out the reason :). I forgot to import and include HttpClient in my app.module.ts file and imports array, making it inaccessible to the app (I think so).

`import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

```
//Router Module for Application level Route
import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BookViewComponent } from './book-view/book-view.component';

//import statement for service
import { BookService } from './book.service';
import { BookHttpService } from './book-http.service';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 

//decorators
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BookViewComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'book/:isbn', component: BookViewComponent }
    ]),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [BookService,BookHttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I forgot to include this  module `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

But the 2nd error is still in place. [SyntaxError: unexpected token: '{' scripts.js:1:5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4TNq.png) . I can't understand why is this an error.

angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "series": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/series",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "series:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "series:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "series:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "series-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "series:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "series:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "series"
}
```

Comment: Because you included styles file in scripts array of angular.json file. They go in styles array

Comment: @Code_maniac I removed the CSS files but the error is still there.

Comment: Need to see your angular.json file

Comment: Do you have any scripts.js file? Going by the screeenshot, it shows that your js file actually has a css content.

Comment: @Code_maniac Thanks, it was throwing the error due to the css file in scripts array,as you said. Now, it's working fine. Thanks a lot.